# проблемы с прошивкой stm32f103c8t6 утилитой st-flash в linux

Tags: linux-mint, hex, stm32

Всем привет! Столкнулся с нелепой ситуацией: написал пробную прошивку в в Linux Mint eclipse Oxigen 3 для stm32f103c8t6 простого мигания светодиодом. После сборки, как и должно быть, получаю файлы .elf и .hex. Заливаю в контроллером при помощи stlinkv2 утилитой st-flash. В терминале показывает, что все успешно прошилось. Но контроллер светодиодом не мигает. Ресэт, выключение-включение не помогает. И еще не получается залить в контроллер файл .elf соответственно, отладка не работает. Самое интересное то, что когда я эту же прошивку скопировал на комп под Windows и залил в контроллер тем же stlinkv2, контроллер завелся. В чем может быть проблема?
При прошивке с винды память контроллера выглядит также, как и прошивка. При прошивке линуксом, в памяти контроллера появляются совсем другие значения.

[image: прошивка виндоусом]

[image: прошивка линуксом]

[image: сам файл прошивки]

[image: плата и программатор]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался:
Нужно было прошивать командой 
./st-flash --format ihex write myapp.hex,
указывающий на hex-формат прошивки.

Удалось победить и отладку, а именно исправить ошибку
reset command not defined for device 'generic tcp/ip'

Ошибка возникала из-за того, что я установил самую новую версию 
gdb hardware debugging release 9.4
 нужно было в eclipse установить 
gdb hardware debugging release 9.3(с ней сразу все заработало).